# Is there a way to create JSON from .csv without importing csv?

Tags: python, json, csv, zapier

I have some simple csv data that is coming live from Google Sheets, and I want to format it as JSON using Python so I can post it at an API.

Is there a way to do this without importing `csv`?

Zapier doesn't support importing anything other than `requests`.

Example csv data:

```
Name,ID,Price,Qty
Row 1,123,100,1
Row 2,123,56,2
Row 3,123,90,3
Row 4,213,68,5
Row 5,765,987,789
Row 6,123,123,123
```

Update: This is where I'm at:

[Zapier screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BU6k.png)

But I'm getting the error:

```
    File "<string>", line 11, in the_function
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Comment: do a string replace of `Row` with `[` and a string replace of `\n` with `],` and then just toss it inside another set of `[ ]` ? Might be helpful to specify how you want the outputted JSON to look like if not a list of lists

Comment: Not sure this would work with a variable number of rows, I think it needs to loop through and format.

Comment: Sure, it's detailed here: https://zapier.com/apps/code/help#requiring-or-using-external-libraries

Comment: not sure how having more rows or less rows would make my comment not work

Comment: Just saw the updated question - I'd recommend putting an expected format of your output JSON

Comment: How do you mean...? Excuse my unfamiliarity with python, I'm not a developer, hence using Zapier.

Comment: According to their [documentation](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#requiring-or-using-external-libraries) - `Only the standard Python library and requests is available`. So `import csv` should be allowed as it is a standard Python library.

Comment: what do you want the .json you get to look like? would you want `[[1,123,100,1],[2,123,56,2], ...` or something else like `[{"name": "Row", "ID": 1, "Price": 100, "Qty":1}, ...` or something else?

Comment: have you heard of `csvkit`? It has a `csvjson` program described [here](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvjson.html)

Comment: [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is a very simple delimited text format, so you should be able to read and convert it into JSON object (equivalent to a Python dictionary) format with little difficulty.

Comment: @Quinn I would say more like the latter

Comment: @MartinEvans Interesting, I feel like I'm getting somewhere, but I can't seem to get it working. I might post an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Like others have mentioned, `data.csv = ...` isn't valid python, hence your error.

To give some context, your python code is set up like so:

```py
# this is done automatically, behind the scene
s = """Name,ID,Price,Qty
Row 1,123,100,1
Row 2,123,56,2
Row 3,123,90,3
Row 4,213,68,5
Row 5,765,987,789
Row 6,123,123,123"""

input_data = {"data": s}
```

So to parse that, your code should be something like:

```py
import csv

result = {}
with csv.reader(input_data['data'].splitlines()) as r:
    for line in r:
        # organize the data how you want
        pass

return result
```

That should let you transform the data into any shape you want!

You mentioned wanting to send the data to an API - you can do that in this code step too. See [HTTP examples](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#introductory-http-example).

Comment: Cool! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

The error is because data.csv is not a valid variable name, you can't have '.' in there.

I don't know how Zapier works but if you're trying to read the data from a file called 'data.csv' and if you want an output in the following format

`[{"name": "Row", "ID": 1, "Price": 100, "Qty":1}, ...`

Then try

```
# Reading each line the data.csv file into a list
with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    input = f.readlines()
input = [i.strip('\n\r') for i in input] # Strip new line characters

s = "["
for k in input[1:]: # For every line except for the header
  s += '{{"Name": "{}", "ID": {}, "Price": {}, "Qty": {}}}, '.format(*k.split(","))
s += "]"
```

If you're trying parse the test from the variable "input_data" (which it looks like you're trying to do) then try.

```
input = input_data['data'].split("\n")

s = "["
for k in input[1:]: # For every line except for the header
  s += '{{"Name": "{}", "ID": {}, "Price": {}, "Qty": {}}}, '.format(*k.split(","))
s += "]"
```

Comment: I see, that's interesting, but where is it getting the data from? I've shared a screengrab above.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [zapier documentation](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#requiring-or-using-external-libraries):

> Only the standard Python library and requests is available.

So `import csv` and `import json` would be allowed as they are standard Python libraries.

It then just depends on what format you want the JSON output format to be. A very simple and straightforward conversion would be to use the standard Python `csv` and `json` libraries as follows:

```
import csv
import json

with open('data.csv') as f_input:   
    data = list(csv.DictReader(f_input))

with open('data.json', 'w') as f_output:
    json.dump(data, f_output, indent=3)
```

Giving you an output JSON file as follows:

```json
[
   {
      "Name": "Row 1",
      "ID": "123",
      "Price": "100",
      "Qty": "1"
   },
   {
      "Name": "Row 2",
      "ID": "123",
      "Price": "56",
      "Qty": "2"
   },
   {
      "Name": "Row 3",
      "ID": "123",
      "Price": "90",
      "Qty": "3"
   },
   {
      "Name": "Row 4",
      "ID": "213",
      "Price": "68",
      "Qty": "5"
   },
   {
      "Name": "Row 5",
      "ID": "765",
      "Price": "987",
      "Qty": "789"
   },
   {
      "Name": "Row 6",
      "ID": "123",
      "Price": "123",
      "Qty": "123"
   }
]
```